# Can racerJS use native mongo ObjectIDs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, derbyjs, racerjs

I noticed that the [latest commit](https://github.com/codeparty/racer-db-mongo/commit/26d1761a6a0367fc74529e6ccee4514df6cfbf6b) to Racer's Mongo DB driver has to do with casting Racer's ids to Mongo ObjectIDs, any idea how to get that to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This driver is for Racer 0.3. Current version is 0.5. A lot of things have been changed: Share.js added, LiveDB, Redis, etc. You should use this driver now: https://github.com/share/livedb-mongo

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, there's no reference to objectIds whatsoever in this one, seems it is not possible, thanks anyways.